# Android AdapterView cannot display database records in some device

Tags: android, android-adapterview

I would like to ask some question about AdapterView.

In my application, there is an activity which retrieve data from database and display them in AdapterView.
However, when i install the application in different devices, I found that the part I have just mentioned could only function on some devices. The others cannot show the database results.

Here is my code:

```
 private void showResults(String query) {

    Cursor cursor = searchCustByInputText(query);

    if (cursor == null) {
        //
    } else {
        // Specify the columns we want to display in the result
        String[] from = new String[] {
                "cust_code", 
                "chinese_name"};

        // Specify the Corresponding layout elements where we want the columns to go
        int[] to = new int[] {     
                R.id.scust_code,
                R.id.schinese_name};

        // Create a simple cursor adapter for the definitions and apply them to the ListView
        SimpleCursorAdapter customers = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.cust_list_item, cursor, from, to);
        mListView.setAdapter(customers);

        // Define the on-click listener for the list items
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Cursor c = (Cursor) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String cust_code = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cust_code"));

                if (callFromAct.equals("Main")) {

                    String pay_term = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("pay_term"));
                    String chinese_name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("chinese_name"));
                    String english_name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("english_name"));
                    String address_1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address_1"));
                    String address_2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address_2"));
                    String address_3 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address_3"));
                    String address_4 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address_4"));
                    String contact = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("contact"));
                    String telephone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("telephone"));
                    String last_order_date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("last_order_date"));

                    //Pass data to another Activity 
                    Intent it = new Intent(CustEnqActivity.this, CustEnqDetailsActivity.class);                 
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("cust_code", cust_code);
                    bundle.putString("pay_term", pay_term);
                    bundle.putString("chinese_name", chinese_name);
                    bundle.putString("english_name", english_name);
                    bundle.putString("address_1", address_1);
                    bundle.putString("address_2", address_2);
                    bundle.putString("address_3", address_3);
                    bundle.putString("address_4", address_4);
                    bundle.putString("contact", contact);
                    bundle.putString("telephone", telephone);
                    bundle.putString("last_order_date", last_order_date);
                    it.putExtras(bundle);                    
                    startActivity(it);                  
                }
                else {

                    returnToCallingAct(cust_code);
                }                                        
                //searchView.setQuery("",true);
            }
        });            
    }
}
```

Besides, I discovered there were two warnings in my logcat.

1. The constructor SimpleCursorAdapter(Context, int, Cursor, String[], int[]) is deprecated
2. AdapterView is a raw type. References to generic type AdapterView should be parameterized

Are they related to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a class that extends BaseAdapter and use ViewHolders for performance

eg:

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<ListData>();
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        Context context;


        public MyBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListData> myList) {
                this.myList = myList;
                this.context = context;
                inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);        // only context can also be used
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
                return myList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public ListData getItem(int position) {
                return myList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

                if(convertView == null) {
                        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, null);
                        mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
                        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
                } else {
                        mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                mViewHolder.tvTitle = detail(convertView, R.id.tvTitle, myList.get(position).getTitle());
                mViewHolder.tvDesc  = detail(convertView, R.id.tvDesc,  myList.get(position).getDescription());
                mViewHolder.ivIcon  = detail(convertView, R.id.ivIcon,  myList.get(position).getImgResId());

                return convertView;
        }

        // or you can try better way
        private TextView detail(View v, int resId, String text) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(resId);
                tv.setText(text);
                return tv;
        }

        private ImageView detail(View v, int resId, int icon) {
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(resId);
                iv.setImageResource(icon); //

                return iv;
        }

        private class MyViewHolder {
                TextView tvTitle, tvDesc;
                ImageView ivIcon;
        }
}
```

More info/example:
http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/#sthash.lNGSCiyB.dpbs

Comment: Does it mean that I have to replace SimpleCursorAdapter with class that extends BaseAdapter and ViewHolders in my program??